# "PrivateImplementationDetails" function when decompiling a C #

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I'm rebuilding a library programmed in C # and need help with a `Switch` statement, I have the following code snippet using the `<PrivateImplementationDetails> .ComputeStringHash ()` function generated during compilation. My question is, what is the function that I should use? Will I get the same result using `sss.GetHashCode()`?

Currently the error that is presented to me is `Can not resolve symbol 'PrivateImplementationDetails'`.

```
 switch (<PrivateImplementationDetails>.ComputeStringHash(sss)) {
    case 0x1315fc:
        if (sss == "ASD") {
            break;
        }
        goto Label_0105;

    case 0x15c3dc:
        if (sss == "JKL") {
            break;
        }
        goto Label_0105;
 }
```

Comment: Your decompiler is not smart enough to recognize this construct, somewhat understandable since this code-gen was added just recently.  The original code simply had `switch (sss) { case "ASD": etc }`.  Generating the hash makes that a lot faster.

Comment: @HansPassant So, if I use `sss.GetHashCode()` instead of recoding the switch (the switch is very long), will this work? Thanks

Comment: No.  You are not supposed to use any hash code at all.  The C# compiler auto-generates it when you write a plain switch statement for a string.  Try it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time the question was asked, the generated IL was relatively new, so the decompilers hadn't been updated to support it. Essentially the decompiler revealed some of the underlying .NET framework code and the [hash function](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compiler/MethodBodySynthesizer.Lowered.cs,c6390aa114fbd516) used to support string switch statements.

Now, a year or so later, the decompilers have been updated so they should just show a `switch` statement like this:

```
switch (sss)
{
    case "ASD":
    // do something
    break;
    case "JKL":
    // do something
    break
}
```

I've tested this with [DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and can confirm it shows this correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This code below is the right one to run your code without any error:

```
internal sealed class PrivateImplementationDetails
{
    internal static uint ComputeStringHash(string s)
    {
        uint num = new uint();
        if (s != null)
        {
            num = 0x811c9dc5;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                num = (s[i] ^ num) * 0x1000193;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

And remove the `<>` around `PrivateImplementationDetails`

Comment: But why, when Hans already explained that it was just a misunderstanding by the decompiler, is this code relevant? And how likely is it to be useful to the OP over a year later (or indeed anyone else when most decompilers will have already updated to handle this)?

Comment: And this is also a code-only answer with little explanation as to what it does or why it works. You could at least mention that it's the [FNV-1a algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) or point to the [C# source code](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compiler/MethodBodySynthesizer.Lowered.cs,c6390aa114fbd516), which you no doubt referenced to get this.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I just had the same issue and this answer is a perfect solution. So in my case I am using dnSpy to lower (local!) game difficulty level. Once I made changes to desired DLL and wanted to compile... it alerted error. I do not know C#, so I stuck here for a long time until this suggestion to "stupidly simple" to put this piece of code that will emulate hashing. 
Does it work? Yes! Does it do the job? Yes. 
Ultimately: good solution in some cases. 

P.S. Sometimes such solutions without a proper explanation of how it works are better than no solution but an explanation.